# a little confusion over celery terminology

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

hi I am a little confused over `celeryd` and `celeryd_multi` - what is the difference between this two? I mean, so far I have been using `python manage.py celeryd`, but i came across `celeryd_multi` today and couldn't find any explanation. According to the docs, `-c` indicates Number of child processes processing the queue, so if thats the case, whats `celeryd_multi's` usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

celeryd command launches single celery worker. celeryd_multi command manages multiple celery workers. With celeryd_multi you can start/stop/restart multiple celery workers.

celeryd_multi can be used to manage multiple celeryd workers listening to different queues:

```
$ celeryd-multi start image video data -c 3
```

This command is equivalent to:

```
$ celeryd -n image.myhost -c 3
$ celeryd -n video.myhost -c 3
$ celeryd -n data.myhost -c 3
```